# Vue deep copy object not changing value

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have a vue component that has a deep copy of an asset called cachedAsset. It has a value called toDelete to mark a file for soft deletion. I have the following code

```
markForDeletion(files) {
          const thisComponent = this;
          files.forEach((file) => {
              thisComponent.cachedAsset.files.find(f => file.id === f.id).toDelete = true;
          });
      }
```

this works as intended it changes the .toDelete to true and the file is filterd out in a process further down the line.

The issue that I am having is with restoring the file back to the component with the following code

```
restoreFilesFromDeletion(items) {
          items.forEach((item) => {
              this.cachedAsset.files.find(f => item.id === f.id).toDelete = false;
          });
      }
```

With this code it should set the .toDelete back to false but it is not doing that and I get no errors or anything in the console.

Can anyone tell me why this is not updating the .toDelete back to false when executed .?

Edit 1

this is what I have now

```
restoreFilesFromDeletion(items) {
          items.forEach((item) => {
              let files = this.cachedAsset.files.find(f => item.id === f.id)
              this.$set(files, 'toDelete', false)
          });
      }
```

it seems to be setting it but the true still does not change to false ..

am I still missing something ? any further advice that can be given...

Comment: You should be using `this.$set` in both mark and restore. Your question mentions a deep copy but then nothing else is said of it and no code is shown regarding this copy or how it's implemented to effect the restoration. Maybe the problem is there instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens when data is deeply nested.
Try this [Vue.delete](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-delete).
and also see [Reactivity in Depth](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html).

Comment: If i were to use thje Vue.delete, how would I be able to restore the file from being soft deleted  that is the question. I don't want to to a final delete until the edit form is saved.

Comment: Any other suggestions on either how i can get this to work i did not find a solution in the documentation and Vue.delete will not work for my purposes

Comment: I have also mention "Reactivity in Depth"  link where you can find "$set()" method for changing state. $set() method works for deeply nested data.

Answer (score 0):

After re-analyzing the results with some console tests, I found that I had an error elsewhere in my code, once I fixed that the delete and restore are working properly.

Thank you for your assistance, it has given me more knowledge and insight on reactivity and the `$set` method.